# OneToMany Relationship with Symfony2 and Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

I keep getting a `null` result when I try to retrieve the many side of my bi-directional relation.

In My Tool Entity, I have

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->instances = new ArrayCollection;
}


/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $toolId;


/* @var ArrayCollection things
*
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Instance", mappedBy="tool")
*/
private $instances;




public function getInstances(){
    print "In the get";
    var_dump($this->instances);
    return $this->instances;
}
```

Then on the other side, I have

```
class Instance {
/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $instanceId;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $serialnumber;

/**
 * @var boolean
 */
private $inServiceFlag = '1';

 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tool", inversedBy="instances")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tool_id", referencedColumnName="tool_id")
 */
private $tool;
```

When I view an instance, I can see the tool, but when I view the tool I can see an array of the instances. I always get a null value.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your `@JoinColumn` annotation is correct?

In the annotation, I see `referencedColumnName="tool_id"`, but on your Tool entity, I see `private $toolId;`

Everything else looks correct to me, according to [the docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) (assuming these entities are in the same namespace, of course)

Comment: I believe that the referencedColumnName must match the table column name and that is tool_id. The private $toolId is the entity name. Do I need to put my own logic in the function getInstances? I figured that Doctrine should automatically get the related items.

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, you are correct that Doctrine should be filling in the blanks for you. An easy way to check that your `@JoinColumn` annotation isn't causing the problem is to ensure your Tool entity has a private key (add an `@Id` annotation if you don't have one already) and remove your `@JoinColumn` annotation - Doctrine should guess some sensible defaults based on your `@ManyToOne` annotation. (See also: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-joincolumn)